# How to draw a resized picture instead of line? (html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

So we can have for example such function to draw a line

```
function drawLine(g, n, x1, y1, x2, y2){
    g.beginPath();
    g.lineWidth = n > 0 ? n : 1;
    g.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 128, 32)";
    g.moveTo(x1, y1);
    g.lineTo(x2, y2);
    g.stroke();
}
```

but what if we want to draw an image instead of line (resized in respect for line size, with alpha channel).

How to do such thing?

Comment: Inserting an image or drawing an arbitrary image? http://goo.gl/hxMFc and http://goo.gl/xAMBj

Comment: Hmm ... you could draw the line on a blank canvas, get its image data, then find the line and use the coordinates to pluck out pixels from an actual image ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `drawImage()` method of the context, but first [`translate`, `rotate`, and `scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas) the context. The image will come out as a long thin line rotated as you like.

**Edit**: I've put a live [example of this technique online](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_image_line.html), wrapping the technique up as a function.